# AS3: AIR Android: How to add an input text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, textinput, android-touch-event, air-android

I made a game that requires the player to  type their answer. The following code is for the desktop version. I'm making a mobile version of the game and am having trouble with it. How can I code this so that the player can type their answer through touch events and tapping?

```html
var answer:int;
answer = int(answer_txt.text)
```

Comment: Unless you do use some specific touch capabilities, like multitouch, or gestures, or touch size and phases, just resort to regular mouse events (e.g. **MouseEvent.CLICK**), they should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

simply add an inputbox to allow your users when touch it, add their answer

```
var textInput:TextField;
textInput.background = true;
textInput.restrict = "0-9";
textInput.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
textInput.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
textInput.type = "input";
textInput.softKeyboard = SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER
addChild(textInput)
```

also you can use addTextFormat to change your font,and fontSize ,...